# Checkbox hard to click on firefox mobile

Tags: html, firefox, checkbox, mobile, checked

I've been having trouble clicking a checkbox on firefox mobile. This seems to be the case sitewide.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

I've tried increasing the size of the checkbox and it wasn't very helpful and I can't make it to big for the project that I'm working on.

Would there be a way to resolve this issue for firefox mobile?

```css
#checkbox {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
```